# Trazer todos os resultados fora do foreach

Tags: php, foreach

Não estou conseguindo trazer todos os resultados fora do foreach. Segue o código:

```
 foreach ($_POST['filtroOpt'] as $key=> $value){

          $filtro = "AND ".$value." LIKE '%".$_POST['term'][$key]."%' ";
          echo $filtro."</br>";
}
```

O echo dentro do foreach exibe todos os resultados que eu quero, porém, quando tento colocá-lo para fora ele exibe somente o primeiro resultado. Tentei algumas coisas como por exemplo o array mas não tive sucesso.

Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 0):

O empecilho foi sanado com o implode como no exemplo abaixo:

```
foreach ($_POST['filtroOpt'] as $key=> $value){
 $filtro[] = "AND ".$value." LIKE '%".$_POST['term'][$key]."%' ";
//echo $filtro;
$Output = implode("", $filtro);
}
```

Chamado o $Output fora do foreach deu certo.